# Send commands from command line to a running Python script in Unix

Tags: python, unix, client-server

I want to build a script that can be controlled while running from another scripts. For example I want to run my script like this:

```
~: Server &
```

and be able to run one of it's functions like:

```
~: client func1
```

Upon my searches I find signal module that have something like I want, but it's signals are predefined and I can not send signals of my own.

I even though of a client/server implementation using a network framework but I think it's too much for the abilities that I want my script to have.

Thank you all.

Comment: Are you assuming that the client and server are running on the same machine? If not, you will need networking.

Comment: I use Gtk signals - whitout a window or graphic part - and everithing is ok and fast. But I use Openbox/Gnome. I think platform-native signal method do the job with litle overhead.

Comment: @merlin2011 I prefer to assume the client and server are running on the same machine since in other way as I said it'll be too far more than what I want!

Comment: @Shahinism, I would not be so sure. I am preparing an answer for you which I think you'll find simpler than you expect.

Comment: @merlin2011 Thank you, as you and oodograss said, socket was the solution.

Comment: @Shahinism, You are welcome. I hope others will find the sample code below useful too. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are only trying to send commands one-directionally to a server, it is *easier than you think*, using Python's [Sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html). The code samples are of course barebones in the sense that they do not do error handling, and do not call `recv` multiple times to make sure the message is complete. This is just to give you an idea of how few lines of code it takes to process commands.

Here is a server program that simply receives messages and prints to `stdout`. Note that we use threading so that the server can listen to multiple clients at once.

```
import socket
from threading import Thread


MAX_LENGTH = 4096

def handle(clientsocket):
  while 1:
    buf = clientsocket.recv(MAX_LENGTH)
    if buf == '': return #client terminated connection
    print buf

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

PORT = 10000
HOST = '127.0.0.1'

serversocket.bind((HOST, PORT))
serversocket.listen(10)

while 1:
    #accept connections from outside
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()

    ct = Thread(target=handle, args=(clientsocket,))
    ct.start()
```

Here is a client program that sends commands to it.

```
import socket
import sys


HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 10000
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

while 1:
    msg = raw_input("Command To Send: ")
    if msg == "close":
       s.close()
       sys.exit(0)
    s.send(msg)
```

Comment: @Shahinism, Thank you for the edits. As you can see, I did not get everything when I was stripping down these examples. :P

Comment: Can you broadcast a message to multiple instances of the interpreter? Like if you have a web server running, can you broadcast a signal to every handler that is currently running and say "Log out your user if he has this id"?

Comment: @KevinOrr, I think you are looking for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603852/multicast-in-python), but if that is insufficient to help you, please ask a new question.

Comment: I tried to fix/edit a bug in the above code, but it got rejected for some reason. Anyway, the thread in the server code is started using `ct.run()` instead of `ct.start()` which means it's not actually executing in parallel (as a thread) but as a normal blocking code. This means that multiple connections cannot be handled simultaneously as intended by the threading and statement `serversocket.listen(10)`. I.e, the function `accept()` will only be reached when a client is finished with it's connection in the handling function.

Answer (score 4):

So you need to talk to a running process right? What about the idea of unix domain socket?

In your server you can build up a socket on a path of your unix file system, then talk to that socket in you client, like described in this link I googled:

http://pymotw.com/2/socket/uds.html