# Subscribing to UDP multicast with Python

Tags: python, udp, multicast

This topic has been covered in a good amount of detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603852/multicast-in-python), unfortunately, I'm still running into some trouble.

I'm trying to subscribe to a stream of motion-capture data from a windows box on my network. The mo-cap server is broadcasting over my network, and I can pick up the data with wireshark on my OS X machine ('the target'). I see that a message originating from the origin ip `204.102.224.2` (windows) broadcasting on `239.255.42.99` via UDP, to port `1511` is going out, as desired.

My python code is as follows:

```
PORT = 1511
MULTICAST_ADDRESS = '239.255.42.99'
SOCKET_BUFSIZE = 1024

datasock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
datasock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
datasock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
datasock.bind((MULTICAST_ADDRESS, PORT))
mreq = struct.pack("=4sl", socket.inet_aton(MULTICAST_ADDRESS), socket.INADDR_ANY)
datasock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 32)
datasock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, 1)
datasock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, SOCKET_BUFSIZE)
datasock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

while 1:
    data = datasock.recv(rx.MAX_PACKETSIZE)
    packet = rx.unpack(data, version=version)
    if type(packet) is rx.SenderData:
        version = packet.natnet_version
        #print("NatNet version received:", version)
    if type(packet) in [rx.SenderData, rx.ModelDefs, rx.FrameOfData]:
        packet_dict = packet._asdict()
        all_bodies = packet_dict['rigid_bodies']
        for body in all_bodies:
            contortion = body._asdict()['orientation']
            euler = Quat([elem for elem in contortion]).equatorial
```

I think for my current issue it is safe to ignore some of the code in the loop, as some of it derives from a helper library I'm using (optirx). Note that I didn't start out with all the options, but decided to include all of them to see what should stay and what can go. I've tried various combinations and permutations. I'm on OS X 10.10.3

Comment: So what is your question or where are your issues?  What works and what does not work?

Comment: The gist of it is I can see the multicast on my Mac from the windows machine in wire shark, but was never able to grab it with this code. I've tried many combos of the above options.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
datasock.bind((MULTICAST_ADDRESS, PORT))
```

You shouldn't bind the socket to the multicast address.  You should bind it to `'0.0.0.0'`.  The `setsockopt` call with `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` takes care of joining the multicast group.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this out when I'm in the lab again. Will report back.