# Verify if there are multicast data sent in multicast group?

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I've been searching and testing all over the place but haven't find anything that works as I need it to.

I want to verify, with python, if there are any data sent in a multicast group without disturb the multicast distribution.

I've tried this ([Multicast in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603852/multicast-in-python)) but that tended to freeze the multicast. What I did was to run that in a loop through a load of multicast groups, everyone on the same IP but different ports.

Have also tried to just using a raw socket and try to receive udp packages from the multicast group without success.

Anyone that may point me in right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article [Multicast in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603852/multicast-in-python) worked. I just had to put a time.sleep(1) between the join and the data request.