# Gstreamer no longer works after putting code on new device

Tags: audio, udp, gstreamer, multicast, gstreamer-1.0

So I was successfully using gstreamer to listen to a multicast group using this command:

`gst_str = "udpsrc multicast-group=239.192.60.1 port=60001 ! application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio,clock-rate=(int)48000,encoding-name=(string)OPUS,payload=(int)112 ! rtpopusdepay ! opusdec ! autoaudiosink"`

I had to switch devices I was listening on and my gstreaming object is no longer working. When I go to print out the data from my gstream there is nothing.

At first I had an issue that the multicast route wasn't joined, but I was able to fix that and confirm that I am receiving data on my new device from this ip using this script:

```
import socket
import struct

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603852/multicast-in-python
MCAST_GRP = '239.192.60.1'
MCAST_PORT = 60001

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

sock.bind((MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT))
mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GRP), socket.INADDR_ANY)

sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

while True:
  data = sock.recv(16)
  print (data);
```

I am unsure how to narrow down the issue from here. As I am receiving the multicast packets on my new device, and not sure why gstream would stop working on a new device.

Any guidance is appreciated!

BTW: Both devices are running ubuntu

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Comment: I was able to get gstreamer to pick up data now by specifying both the interface name and the ip address