# How to receive UDP traffic from multicast adress with Python?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have an ethernet device sending UDP packets to multicast address 224.0.2.2 on port 42102. I'm able to capture packets from wireshark or tcpdump, but when I try to open a socket and bind it to multicast port I never receive anything.

I've tried many variations of the following. I've tried running as sudo, etc with no luck. The ip address of the connected interface (enp12s0) is 10.13.1.100.

```
import socket
import struct

def mc_recv(fromnicip, mcgrpip, mcport):
    # This creates a UDP socket
    sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM, \
            proto=socket.IPPROTO_UDP, fileno=None)

    bindaddr = (mcgrpip, mcport)
    sock.bind(bindaddr)

    mreq = struct.pack("=4s4s", socket.inet_aton(mcgrpip), socket.inet_aton(fromnicip))
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print(f"Received packet from {addr}: {data.decode('utf-8')}")

def main():

    fromnicip = '10.13.1.100'
    mcgrpip = '224.0.2.2'
    mcport = 42102

    mc_recv(fromnicip, mcgrpip, mcport)
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

So far, I haven't received any UDP packets in any configuration.

For reference, if I run tshark with

```
sudo tshark -f "host 224.0.2.2" -f "port 42102" -i enp12s0
```

the captured packet summaries look like

```
   59 0.949480840  10.13.1.113 → 224.0.2.2    UDP 130 42402 → 42102 Len=84
   60 1.000030440  10.13.1.113 → 224.0.2.2    UDP 130 42402 → 42102 Len=84
```

Update:
I've tried modifying code according to suggestions in:
[How do you UDP multicast in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603852/how-do-you-udp-multicast-in-python)
(and other similar questions) to no avail.

However, on a lark I tried the code above on a windows boot on the same machine and it works. I guess it has something to do with the network configuration on the linux side, but I'm at a loss as to what the issue may be. I tried

```
sudo ufw status
```

and it returned

```
Status: inactive
```

Is there something else that could explain what's going on such that wireshark can see the traffic but not a python socket?